Adding external library to maven project
I am using an externally compiled jar library in my project. I added it to the pom as follows. Maven also runs flawlessly in the development environment. It sees the external source library, but when I produce the jar file of my project, it does not see the external source library I added to my project:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>Automation.BDaq</groupId>
            <artifactId>Automation.BDaq</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}\src\lib\Automation.BDaq.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

What can I do to fix this issue?

You probably need to add it to some form of repo - Can you check with your team to see what they might be using (something like Nexus, or Artifactory), and follow the instructions you can find online to make it available there.

System dependency. Are you sure the dependency is present on the machine, where you run the jar? And are you sure the path resolves correctly after building the jar?

This has been asked many times before. Search previous answers before asking.

Can I add artifactory even though there is no pom maven jar? "mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path/to/Automation.BDaq.jar -DgroupId=Automation.BDaq -DartifactId=Automation.BDaq -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar"
I tried to add it this way but I couldn't add it.
